# Find any exists with conditions in one queryset Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Now i have 2 model like this:

```
class RequestSession(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequest)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Now i want find all `ServiceRequest` have one or more `RequestSession` have `start_time__gte=now()` with one query from `ServiceRequest`. I want it keep instance `queryset` for paging auto in django

It will have result same this :

```
result = []
queryset = ServiceRequest.objects.all()
current_time = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
for service_request in queryset:
    if RequestSession.objects.filter(start_time__gte=current_time, request=service_request).exists():
        result.append(service_request)
```

But like you see, it return array. I hoop it is `queryset`. I dont want create `queryset` back with all `id` in array `result` because i think it will slow.

How to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this,

```
ServiceRequest.objects.filter(requestsession__start_time__gte=current_time)
```

For more examples, refer this section, [**Lookups that span relationships** - [Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)